# Why mention Sarajevo in "In Purgatory's Shadow"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, behind-the-scenes

The DS9 Episode "In Purgatory's Shadow" (5x14) was written by Ira Steven Behr and Robert Hewitt Wolfe and directed by Gabrielle Beaumont.

**Is there any commentary from any of them to why they mentioned Sarajevo in the show?**

The war in my home country had just ended by the time of filming and Sarajevo was under siege for the most part of the war (and still record holder for a  capital city held under siege in recent memory, 1425 days).

Comment: Sarajevo is mentioned as the name of one of the Starfleet ships that "have been lost in the Gamma Quadrant for years". Sarajevo, historically speaking, is primarily known for being the location of the assassination of Archduke Franz Ferdinand, starting World War I. In-universe, the ship would most likely be named for the World War I reference.

Comment: i disagree there. DS9 was made in mid to late 90s. and the War in Balkans was on CNN almost every day in that period. Sarajevo has the honour of being the first city with a tram in the world, surrounded by 4 mountain peaks, being a host to winter Olympics of 84 and many, many other things other than the assassination of Franz by Gavrilo Princip in 1914. But then again I cant be sure coz I didn't speak to Behr about it or did enough research on the subject.

Comment: I specifically said "in-universe". "Starfleet", in the 24th century, would have named the ship primarily after the city where World War I started. For "Starfleet", the four-year siege of Sarajevo was *not* a little over 20 years ago and a very influential local matter. For comparison, what do you know about the Second Congo War (1998-2003)?

Comment: Out-of-universe there is a possibility that Sarajevo was a reference to the recent war, not (just) World War I. DS9 is very war-heavy and by the time of season 5 the main Dominion War arc would have been plotted out. However, in the main war arc there is never a point where a certain region (city, country, planet) is under siege for a prolonged time. There are points where large-scale destruction (and mass murder) occur but this happens very quickly. The only point where a longer siege does happen the besieged are the bad guys and I don't think Behr made that mistake.

Comment: For reference: list of Federation starships named after cities: Baton Rouge, Budapest, Cairo, Charleston, Chicago, Constantinople, Denver, Gettysburg, Havana, Leeds, Manila, Melbourne, Omaha Nebraska, Philadelphia, Portland, Sarajevo, Syracuse, Trieste, Tripoli, Veracruz. Source: Memory Alpha, "Federation starships".